# Cannot find -l<library> in Code::Blocks Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, opengl, codeblocks, glfw

I'm trying to create a window using GLFW on Ubuntu. I downloaded GLFW through an `apt-get` command and added it in `Build Options -> Linker Settings`. However, when I try compiling the program it gives me an error saying

`ld      cannot find -lGLFW`

I've searched the internet and I couldn't find what to do when this happens in Code::Blocks. What can I do to fix this problem?

I've read something like I need to add some options, but I don't know which ones and where exactly.

Note: I'm using GCC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect of your [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49127354/1362568),
adding `glfw` to the **Link libraries** in **Global compiler settings**
is that `libglfw` will be added to the linkage of every project that your
build with that compiler (presumably GCC).

This is quite unnecessary. Simply do the same thing in your *project's*
**Build options** instead:-

- From the **Workspace** tree-view, navigate:  -> **Build options** -> **{Debug|Release**} -> **Linker settings**
  -> **Link libraries**
- Enter `glfw`
- OK out
- Rebuild

Comment: Yup, this helped. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

Use `-lglfw`.

Library names are case-sensitive.  `-lGLFW` != `-lgflw`.

For instance:

- On my Debian 9 system [`pkg-config --libs glfw3`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) gives me:

  ```
  -lglfw
  ```

  At:

  ```
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglfw.so
  ```
- And `pkg-config --libs gl` gives:

  ```
  -lGL
  ```

  Corresponding to:

  ```
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
  ```

Comment: So where do I add this in Code::Blocks?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I fixed my problem.

This is so weird. Thanks to genpfault answer I found out that my `libglfw.so` file is in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` directory.

Everything worked after I deleted `GLFW` from the *Build Options* and added it to *global compiler settings -> linker settings* (I added glfw in link libraries) and in *search directories -> Linker* I added `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Everything Compiled.